# Android : Load image with Picasso onBitMapLoaded not called

Tags: android, picasso

I'm trying to share image on Instagram in my app. I've url of the image and using Picasso library to download image.

```
Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Loaded");
                File outputDir = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(); // context being the Activity pointer
                try {
                    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("instagram", "png", outputDir);
                    outputFile.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,ostream);
                    ostream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Image downloaded");
                    shareOnInstagram(Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(target);
```

But onBitmapLoaded is never being called. Is there any other way to share image on Instagram from a url? The intent which share on Instagram takes  `Intent.EXTRA_STREAM` parameter which should be a `media path on device`.
How do I convert an image from a url into that type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43134498/5488468   Try This it may be worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picasso only keeps weak reference to target, so in your case it will be garbage collected. As a result, onBitmapLoaded is not being called.

You should store strong reference to target (make target member of your class).

Answer (score 1):

I using this approach

```
public class ShareToOtherApp extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Uri> {


    @Override
    protected Uri doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {

        return bitmaps.length > 0 ? BitmaptoUri(bitmaps[0]) : null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Uri uri) {


        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        if (uri != null) {
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        }

        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image");
        chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        MyApp.GetContext().startActivity(chooserIntent);

    }

    public File GetSDCardDir(){
        boolean ISSDCard;
        File[] Dirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(MyApp.GetContext(), null);

        ISSDCard = false;
        for (File Dir : Dirs) {
            if (Dir != null) {
                if (Dir.getPath().contains("sdcard")) {
                    ISSDCard = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        File SDCardDir;
        if(ISSDCard && Dirs[Dirs.length -1] != null){
            SDCardDir = Dirs[Dirs.length -1];
        }else{
            SDCardDir = Dirs[0];
        }

        return SDCardDir;
    }

    public Uri BitmaptoUri(Bitmap bitmap){
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
            File file =  new File(GetSDCardDir() , HConstants.IMG_FILE_NAME + ".jpg");

            if(file.getParentFile() != null){
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            }else{
                GetSDCardDir().mkdirs();
            }
            file.createNewFile();

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.close();

            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return uri;
    }
}
```

and finally for using from it.

```
new ShareToOtherApp().execute(bitmap);
```