# Android OOS while drawing UI and load image from local

Tags: android

Any improvement can be done to improve the speed and performance. Can i prevent OOS while load with a lot of large image. I need some suggestion method for me to study thanks.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutParams.height = height * 12 / 100;
        layoutParams.width = height * 12 / 100;
        image_layer.removeAllViews();
        for (final PostImage postImage : PostImageList) {
            if (!postImage.getImage_local_path().equals("")) {
                Bitmap mBitmap = CommonFunctions.loadImageFromLocalStore(getApplicationContext(), postImage.getImage_local_path());
                if (mBitmap != null) {
                    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

                    int width = ((GlobalVars) getApplicationContext()).getScreen_Width(this);

                    Bitmap rBitmap = CommonFunctions.getResizedBitmapDisplaySmall(mBitmap, width);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(rBitmap);

                    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Users activeUser = dbFunctions.queryActiveUser();

                            currentImage = postImage;

                            Intent intent_jump = new Intent();
                            intent_jump.setClass(IssueInfoActivity.this, ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                            intent_jump.putExtra(CommonActivityConstants.DisplayImage, postImage.getImage_local_path());
                            startActivityForResult(intent_jump, 3001);
                        }
                    });
                    image_layer.addView(imageView, layoutParams);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Explain What `OOS` means?

Comment: out of memory @Abhay Koradiya

Comment: Are the images be displayed in a list or in a grid?

Comment: @atarasenko yes the for loop will create the imageview and add to the linearlayout. But linearlayout have a horizontal scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better solution is to use `RecyclerView` instead of `HorizontalScrollView` with `LinearLayout`, it will load only those images that are currently displayed. Also, for effective caching use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). These libraries allow to configure cache size. 
 Sample code:

```
// MainActivity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerView.adapter = ImageListAdapter()
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)
    }
}

// ImageListAdapter
class ImageListAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false)
        return VH(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 100
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
        Picasso.get()
            .load("https://picsum.photos/${100 + position}")
            .into(holder.image)
    }
}

class VH(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val image: ImageView
    init{
        image = view.findViewById(R.id.image)
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to use picasso to save the image to local but it never go in to onBitmapLoaded

Comment: It should be called) Post more code to make it more clear, or perhaps you encounter this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33581706/android-load-image-with-picasso-onbitmaploaded-not-called